# Create Reusable Widget with Forms and Rest API

Tags: reactjs, widget, web-component, spring-security-oauth2

We have a React/Reduct web app. We want to create a reusable form (Which can be integrated into a few public websites). The form captures a few inputs and post to our backend REST API. The REST API is secured with OAuth2 (Spring oAuth).

Question

- What are the best frameworks (Not necessarily react, we are flexible)
  to build a modern reusable widget which supports forms? (We thinking of Webcomponent, Polymer etc)?
- How can we secure the post without
  asking user for authentication (As these will be on a public facing
  page and all users would be new)

Answer (score 0):

React is fine to create the reusable component and  these component should have any authentication responsibility. Public website will get the token and pass with request header to the server. Your component should display the input fields and capture the data from end users.